# iOS: How to get image size when using UIImagepickerController when click on gallery image

Tags: swift3

I am using UIImagepickerController controller in my application and i want to crop the gallery image in circle. I am able to crop the image in circle but if the image size is small then the crop circle is accroding to screen but i want to make crop circle accroding to image.

Is there any way to get the size of image before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot get the size or any meta data before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo of UIImagepickerController.

but there is alternative , pick the image using AVAsset framework and get the size of the selected image.